# Which is first and why

Tags: sentence-structure

First phrase

> - Er spielte Tennis, obwohl er krank war.
> - Er war krank, obwohl er Tennis spielte.

Second phrase

> - Sie ist nicht glücklich, trotzdem hat sie im Lotto gewonnen.
> - Sie hat im Lotto gewonnen, trotzdem ist sie nicht glücklich.

Comment: That greatly depends on what you want to say i.e. the context!

Comment: Some don't even make sense if you add a lot of context - Causality between playing tennis and not getting sick is hard to imagine....

Answer (score 2):

*Trotzdem* and *obwohl* are both conjunctions that are both used to express the same thing: Causal disagreement between events in time. They differ, however, in the causal order of their arguments:

> **E1**, *trotzdem* **E2**  (Er war krank, spielte aber trotzdem Tennis)

Event **E1** is first in the timely order of events, the disagreeing event that is in the part of the sentence with *trotzdem* **E2** is last (E1 .. E2).

> **E1**, *obwohl* **E2** (Er spielte Tennis, obwohl er krank war)

**E2**, that is in the part of the sentence with the *obwohl* happened first, **E1** happens last (E2 .. E1).

To make matters a bit more difficult, Duden tags the usage of *obwohl* as above as *standardsprachlich* and insists you can also say:

> **E1**, *trotzdem* **E2** (Er spielte Tennis, trotzdem er krank war)

(i.e. the event happening first in time stands with the *trotzdem*, that is Duden claims *trotzdem* and *obwohl* were exact synonyms) (E2 .. E1). I am bold today and dare to disagree with the rule book and this is, in my opinion and experience the less common usage.

This last sentence sounds a bit more common to my ears when *trotzdem* is accentuated on the **second** syllable rather than the first.

Comment: To make matters even worse, there also is **trotz** as in *Trotz seiner Krankheit spielte er Tennis*. I agree with **E1**, *trotzdem* **E2** sounding odd and easily misleading. Sometimes, *obwohl* can replace *trotzdem* without changing word order, but those cases are context-dependent, so they should be avoided, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave the conjunction in the middle, there is a slight difference in meaning.

First off the first example:

> Er spielte Tennis, obwohl er krank war.

It implies that he shouldn't have played tennis because he was sick.

> Er war krank, obwohl er Tennis spielte.

Implies that he shouldn't be sick, because he played tennis, as if him playing tennis should have prevented it.

Second example:

> Sie ist nicht glücklich, trotzdem hat sie im Lotto gewonnen.

means that she was already unhappy, but still won the lottery.

> Sie hat im Lotto gewonnen, trotzdem ist sie nicht glücklich.

means that she won the lottery but is still not happy.

The difference is, that the first one implies some correlation between being unhappy and winning the lottery, while the other one implies a correlation vice versa.

If you want to keep the original meaning but want to exchange the subclauses, you have to move the conjunction as well. But that doesn't sound always natural.

> Obwohl er krank war, spielte er Tennis.

is fine, but

> Trotzdem hat sie im Lotto gewonnen, sie ist nicht glücklich.

is no sentence. For this to work, you have to exchange the conjunction as well, leaving us with

> Obwohl sie im Lotto gewonnen, hat ist sie nicht glücklich.

Comment: Disagree. *Er spielte Tennis, obwohl er krank war* and *Er war krank, obwohl er Tennis spielte*  is entirely different **causality**. So it *does* matter.

Comment: @tofro yeah, i noticed this as well, already changed it. my original thought is the last "paragraph"

Comment: Die Frage ist aber "which is first". Hm.

Comment: @userunknown and like i said, it depends what was there before/what was the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Your first examples have different meanings.

> Er spielte Tennis, obwohl er krank war.

He played tennis despite being sick.

> Er war krank, obwohl er Tennis spielte.

Would rather mean that he was sick despite the fact he played tennis (because sports might be considered being good for your health)

> Sie ist nicht glücklick, trotzdem hat sie im Lotto gewonnen

This does not make sense in German. It literally means that being unhappy did not stop her from winning the lottery. Why would being unhappy stop you from playing the lottery? :)
You'd rather say: Sie ist nicht glücklich obwohl sie im Lotto gewonnen hat.

or

Which means the same as

> Sie hat im Lotto gewonnen, trotzdem ist sie nicht glücklich.

I think trotzdem matches nevertheless while obwohl matches although.

So the reason not to do someting always comes befor trotzdem. While obwohl is always followed by the reason.

**Obwohl sie im Lotto gewonnen hat, ist sie nicht glücklich.**

vs

**Sie hat im Lotto gewonnen. Trotzdem ist sie nicht glücklich.**

Comment: Die Frage ist aber "which is first". Hm.

Comment: @userunknown und genau das habe ich beantwortet...